# Toshiba laptop power light turns off when power button is pressed and the computer doesnt power on

Tags: power-supply, toshiba-laptop

I have a toshiba C655 laptop, As soon as I plug in the adapter the laptop power light turns on with or without the battery, but when I click the power button the power light goes off and nothing happens and it doest power on

Comment: is your question only about the light???, if it is, witch is the relevance of the topic?

Comment: no its about the laptop not being able to power on, the power light only goes off when the power button is pressed nd then nothing happens, the laptop doesnt boot

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issues with a Toshiba laptop.  I had been using a third-party power adapter and battery which caused most of the issues.

At one point, the laptop wouldn't turn on like yours.  The following worked for me:

1. Unplug the power cord.
2. Remove the battery.
3. Hold the power button for 20 seconds (yes this long)
4. Plug in the power cord.
5. Hold the power button for 20 seconds

The laptop should now power on.

Comment: It still wont power on, the power light comes on when i plug in the adapter but immediately i press the power button the light goes off

Answer (score 0):

I disassembled the laptop, removing each component one by one and testing the boot until i found the culprit to the the video cable..I replaced it and it worked

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with the power light comes on when i plug in the adapter but immediately i press the power button the light goes off. I dissembled the laptop, Then reassembled it and it turned out to be the DVD drive was the cause.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! So are you saying it's necessary to apply new thermal paste to the CPU & South Bridge? Or just the DVD drive?  If not the former, please remove it from the answer if it's not part of the solution.

Answer (score 0):

In mine, the problem was where the charging pin connects with the laptop is loose. So I played around with it while pressing the power button and it switched on

Comment: welcome to superuser: - is there any way you could give more detail on the "played around with..." a bit more